# Doubt about collision in characteristic x-rays

Tags: collision, x-rays

Recently I was studying characteristic x-rays and their process of emission, but I don’t understand why the ejected electron of the atom belongs always to the inner shell. Couldn’t the emitted particle hit the electron in another shell, giving rise to a different line in the spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and such lines are observed (L and M lines in [Siegbahn notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegbahn_notation)). However, the [Auger effect](https://www.britannica.com/science/Auger-effect#ref84237) competes with x-ray emission. This reduces the L and M emission more than it does the K, especially for the lighter elements. So, the K lines are generally more prominent.

Comment: So this explains the presence of satellites, right?

Comment: Not really. The satellite lines are a different phenomenon, due to more complicated electron rearrangements.